# Remove values from dataframe with loop r

Tags: r

I have next question. Its rather simple but I cant figure out where I do wrong. I have one year of observations, but the problem is that in the end of the year after 31.12.16 i have shift to 01.01.17 and then repetitions from 2016 year. This can be clearly seen if you look at lines 8572-8574. Therefore, I want to remove those values(everything after 2017 with 2017). My overall database consists of many years to analyse. Therefore manual removing is not the option.

```
           dato horiginal hour mday mon year wday wk
8569 31.12.2016        64   20   31  11  116    6 53
8570 31.12.2016        70   21   31  11  116    6 53
8571 31.12.2016        71   22   31  11  116    6 53
8572 31.12.2016        71   23   31  11  116    6 53
8573 01.01.2017        78    0    1   0  117    0 53
8574 30.10.2016        46   12   30   9  116    0 44
8575 30.10.2016        38   13   30   9  116    0 44
8576 30.10.2016        35   14   30   9  116    0 44
8577 30.10.2016        36   15   30   9  116    0 44
8578 30.10.2016        46   12   30   9  116    0 44
8579 30.10.2016        38   13   30   9  116    0 44
'data.frame':   8629 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ dato     : chr  "01.01.2016" "01.01.2016" "01.01.2016" "01.01.2016" ...
 $ horiginal: num  76 79 78 74 75 71 74 72 71 77 ...
 $ hour     : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ mday     : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ mon      : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ year     : int  116 116 116 116 116 116 116 116 116 116 ...
 $ wday     : int  5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
 $ wk       : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

The last column "wk" is meant week and it the only increasing column in this dataframe (started from 1). My thought process is to make a loop and remove everything if observation is lower than previous values.

I know that looping here probably is not very efficient way, but nothing comes to my mind so far...
so, here is my code:

```
for (i in 1:NROW(newdf_heat$wk)) {
  total.coefs = data.frame()
  if (newdf_heat$wk[i+1]< newdf_heat$wk[i]) {
   total.coefs = newdf_heat[-c(i:nrow(newdf_heat)),]}
  }
```

Im doing something wrong because nothing happens. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: how about `newdf_heat[1:8574, ]`?

Comment: I need to find this shift automatically and then remove everything that is below. I mentioned that manual formatting is not the option because of many dataframes that has to be checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can convert the `dato` column to Date, extract the year, find out the index of row where "2017" occurs for the first time and remove rows from that index.

```
df[1:which.max(format(as.Date(df$dato, "%d.%m.%Y"), "%Y") == "2017") - 1,]

#           dato horiginal hour mday mon year wday wk
#8569 31.12.2016        64   20   31  11  116    6 53
#8570 31.12.2016        70   21   31  11  116    6 53
#8571 31.12.2016        71   22   31  11  116    6 53
#8572 31.12.2016        71   23   31  11  116    6 53
```

---

Or if the year to remove is not "2017" always and the dates are always increasing we can use `diff` to find out the first index where there is drop in the date and remove everything after that.

```
df[1:which.max(diff(as.Date(df$dato, "%d.%m.%Y")) < 0) - 1, ]
```

Also as mentioned in the post `wk` column is always increasing hence, the above `diff` logic can be applied for `wk` column as well which would save us from converting `dato` to Date

```
df[1:which.max(diff(df$wk) < 0) - 1,]
```

Comment: Thanks for help, this way is a bit more complex in comparison to one shown above. But also workable.

Comment: solution with "wk" is even easier to implement.

Answer (score 3):

Has you have seveal year, you could the following:

```
# Extract the cumulative maximum year
my_df$max_year <- cummax(my_df$year)

# Filter those rows which are at least as big as the max_year
my_df[my_df$year >= my_df$max_year, ]

#            dato horiginal hour mday mon year wday wk max_year
# 8569 31.12.2016        64   20   31  11  116    6 53      116
# 8570 31.12.2016        70   21   31  11  116    6 53      116
# 8571 31.12.2016        71   22   31  11  116    6 53      116
# 8572 31.12.2016        71   23   31  11  116    6 53      116
# 8573 01.01.2017        78    0    1   0  117    0 53      117
```

If wk is always increasing you could also use this instead of year, or extract the year as Ronak Shah did it in his answer.

**Data**

```
my_df <- 
  structure(list(dato = c("31.12.2016", "31.12.2016", "31.12.2016", "31.12.2016", "01.01.2017", "30.10.2016", "30.10.2016", "30.10.2016", "30.10.2016", "30.10.2016", "30.10.2016"), 
                 horiginal = c(64L, 70L, 71L, 71L, 78L, 46L, 38L, 35L, 36L, 46L, 38L), 
                 hour = c(20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 12L, 13L), 
                 mday = c(31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 1L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L), 
                 mon = c(11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 0L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L), 
                 year = c(116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 117L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L), 
                 wday = c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
                 wk = c(53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L)), 
            class = "data.frame", row.names = c("8569", "8570", "8571", "8572", "8573", "8574", "8575", "8576", "8577", "8578", "8579"))
```

Comment: This one is quite straightforward. However something is happening with year after  31.12.16. Year and max_year do not match anymore.

Comment: What do you mean with "something is happening?"  `cummax` gives you the maximum value up to this point, thus once you have 117 in the year column, this will always greater or equal to 117 - even if a year 116 comes afterwards